# React - detect if page routing was triggered by keyboard press

Tags: reactjs

I am using React 17 and react-router-dom 5.2.

I have a left sidebar and a main content area.
Each page opened directly via URL, or via click on a link in the navbar it opens a page.

Each page has an entry route such as:

```
<Route path="/testpage" component={TestComponent} />
```

I need to detect if a person entered the page via keyboard or via some other way (mouse click, or direct url entered).

Each compnent has a header:

If a person enters via mouse click or entering the direct URL in the browser nothing changes.

If the person clicked the TAB key until the right link is focused in the navbar, and then the person presses ENTER in the keyboard, the page changes.
And in this case the tabindex should be 1 - `<TestHeader title="" tabIndex={0} />`

I am wondering how can I create a state in this component that holds the information if the page was loaded via keybaord or not...

Ideally I would have that line as the following:

```
<TestHeader title="" tabIndex={enteredByKeyboard ? 1 : 0} />
```

I hope somebody can help

Comment: It's a bit unclear, what's the difference between using the mouse or the keyboard? Or is your question only: "how to detect if it's the initial page load in a session?"

Comment: The requirement is. If a person with screen reader clicks on a link in the left sidebar, then the focus should be in the main content. So that the next click will be after the sidebar.

If a person is not using a screen reader and uses the mouse so normal behavior, this is the focus is at the beginning of the page, so at the first element in the left sidebar. I think this is a silly requirement... but still I am being asked to do it...
This is why I would like to detect how the person "changed page" after kliking ion the sidebar and based on this make the focus on the main element or not

Comment: What if a normal person enters via keyboard and they are not using a screen reader? Many people nagivate using TAB

Comment: so it should behave as if it was a screen reader. After changing page from sidebar with TAB and ENTER then the focus should be on main (on the new opened page) and not on the sidebar

Answer (score 0):

To acknowledge if the user has pressed "Enter" key can be achieved via listening to `keypress` event. The addional logic can take place after the key press is captured.

```
// Execute a function when the user presses a key on the keyboard
input.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
  // If the user presses the "Enter" key on the keyboard
  if (event.key === "Enter") {
    // Cancel the default action, if needed
    event.preventDefault();

    // Trigger the button element with a click
    document.getElementById("myBtn").click();

    // run the custom logic
    // extract this line at the component level, 
    // (as the effects can only be utilised there
    // const navigate = useNavigate();

    const calculateRequiredRoute = event.target.value; 
    // modify the line above to achieve the desired name of that route 
    navigate(calculateRequiredRoute);
  }
});
```

This way it would

Refer :

- https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/navigate
- https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-navigate

Edit:

- `keydown` event can be used for better result, just when the key press was down, instead of on release of the pressed-key.